# maven build issues with Java7

Tags: maven, java-7

Below is my `pom.xml`. We are still using Java7 and when I run `mvn clean install` or `mvn clean package` it creates the Jar just with META-INF and a Manifest file. I do not see the generated classes in the JAR. Please help.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.myorg</groupId>
<artifactId>myInterface</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>Archetype - myClient</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
    <!-- <cxf.version>2.7.17</cxf.version> -->
    <cxf.version>3.1.11</cxf.version>
    <java.version>1.7</java.version>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>

<build>

    <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>


    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>         
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <verbose>true</verbose>
                <fork>true</fork>
                <compilerVersion>1.7</compilerVersion>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${cxf.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>generate-sources</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <sourceRoot>target/main/java</sourceRoot>
                        <defaultOptions>
                        </defaultOptions>
                        <wsdlOptions>

                            <wsdlOption>
                                <wsdl>data/external/wsdls/resourceMgmt.wsdl</wsdl>
                            </wsdlOption>
                            <wsdlOption>
                                <wsdl>data/external/wsdls/customerMgmt.wsdl</wsdl>
                            </wsdlOption>
                            <wsdlOption>                                    <wsdl>data/external/wsdls/customerCompositeView.wsdl</wsdl>
                            </wsdlOption>
                        </wsdlOptions>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <!-- DO NOT include log4j.properties file in your Jar -->
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/log4j.properties</exclude>
                    <exclude>**/my.properties</exclude>
                    <exclude>**/log4j2.xml</exclude>
                </excludes>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <!-- Jar file entry point -->
                        <!-- <mainClass>com.mkyong.core.utils.App</mainClass> -->
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.13.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>myabcdvar</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <generateDirectory>target/main/java</generateDirectory>
                        <schemaDirectory>data/external/xsd/Development</schemaDirectory>
                        <removeOldOutput>false</removeOldOutput>
                        <verbose>true</verbose>
                        <excludeTransitive>true</excludeTransitive>
                        <extension>true</extension>
                        <strict>false</strict>
                        <forceRegenerate>true</forceRegenerate>
                        <!-- <bindingDirectory>data/external/binding</bindingDirectory> -->
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <!--This plugin's configuration is used to store Eclipse m2e settings 
                only. It has no influence on the Maven build itself. -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                        <pluginExecutions>
                            <pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <groupId>
                                        org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2
                                    </groupId>
                                    <artifactId>
                                        maven-jaxb2-plugin
                                    </artifactId>
                                    <versionRange>
                                        [0.8.0,)
                                    </versionRange>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>generate</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                <action>
                                    <ignore></ignore>
                                </action>
                            </pluginExecution>
                            <pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <groupId>
                                        org.apache.cxf
                                    </groupId>
                                    <artifactId>
                                        cxf-codegen-plugin
                                    </artifactId>
                                    <versionRange>
                                        [2.2.1,)
                                    </versionRange>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                <action>
                                    <ignore></ignore>
                                </action>
                            </pluginExecution>
                        </pluginExecutions>
                    </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>[2.17.1,)</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>[2.17.1,)</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-1.2-api</artifactId>
        <version>[2.17.1,)</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>sample</groupId>
        <artifactId>com.sample</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${project.basedir}/localLib/esec.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>




    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-simple</artifactId>
        <version>${cxf.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
                <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
                <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId>
        <version>${cxf.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
        <version>${cxf.version}</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
    </dependency>



    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
        <artifactId>axis2-kernel</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
        <artifactId>axis2-transport-local</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
        <artifactId>axis2-transport-http</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.5</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.13.1</version>
    </dependency>


</dependencies>
```

Comment: please try: `mvn generate-sources`

Comment: @tostao I see an error Failed to collect dependencies at org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2:maven-jaxb2-plugin:jar:0.13.3 -> org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2:maven-jaxb2-plugin-core:jar:0.13.3: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2:maven-jaxb2-plugin-core:jar:0.13.3: Could not transfer artifact org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2:maven-jaxb2-plugin-core:pom:0.13.3 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Received fatal alert: protocol_version

Comment: I used `mvn -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2 clean install` to resolve the issue mentioned in above comment. But still the generated classes are missing from JAR.